# Tag is not getting removed from XML even after returning null from XmlAdapter in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

1. I want to remove the empty tag from XML.

> <Employee>
>           <FirstName>Amit</FirstName>
>           <LastName></LastName>
>           </Employee>

So, in above XML lastName is coming as blank, and currently represented with Empty tags in XML.
But I want the XML in below format:

> <Employee>
>           <FirstName>Amit</FirstName>
>           </Employee>

2. So, extended the XmlAdapter like below:

   ```
   package com.jaxb.domain;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

   import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

   public class NullifyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

     @Override
     public String unmarshal(String strValue) throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return strValue;
     }

     @Override
     public String marshal(String strValue) throws Exception {
       if (StringUtils.isEmpty(strValue)) {
         return null;
       }
       return strValue;
     }

   }
   ```
3. Register it a package level in the package-info.java like below:

   ```
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=NullifyAdapter.class, type=String.class)
   })
   package com.jaxb.domain;

   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
   ```
4. After above changes the XML generated like below:

> <Employee>
>           <FirstName>Amit</FirstName>
>           </LastName>
>           </Employee>

5. In my jaxb binding class the field is defined as:

   ```
   @XmlElement(name = "LastName")
   protected String lastName;
   ```

Please suggest, how to remove lastName completely? There are lot of fields which I need to remove so want a solution on similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the XML's `LastName` element definition with `required=true`.
This will cause the generated `lastName` property to be annotated with `@XmlAttribute(required=true)`.
This way JAXB doesn't serialize the element if it's null.